# set livewallpaper manually

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

i have created live wallpaper in android 2.1.X , now i want to call this code in my activity so that user can set my created live wallpaper through button click just like "Set Wallpaper" button.

As my livewallpaper code extends WallpaperService class so that i can't even call as an intent.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://www.yougli.net/android/live-wallpaper-binding-an-activity-to-the-open-button-of-the-market/). It shows the code for how to add a picker. It uses [WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) which is api level 7, so check you are compiling against the correct version.

The code:

> public class OpenActivity extends
>   Activity {    private int REQUEST_CODE =
>   1;
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
>     super.onCreate(icicle);
>
>     Intent intent = new Intent();
>     intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
>     startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int
>      resultCode, Intent intent)
> {
>   super.onActivityResult(requestCode,
> ```
>
> resultCode, intent);
>         if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE)
>             finish();
>       }
>   }

Comment: Well i tried that earlier but in i want to create live wallpaper based on user creation , so once user done with creating live wallpaper he can set it from the application only..

While this chooser will just open a window and shows wallpaper that are already created.